# Powershell install - No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am having a difficult time installing/updating my powershell modules. I noticed this when I tried installing DBA Tools moudle. Reference links are https://dbatools.io/download/ and https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools.

It's a corporate PC. But I know that I have installed other modules before in the past. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

---

**PS (Admin)>**

`Install-Module DBATools`

- *NOTE: The Install-Module command pauses for many minutes before the command returns a warning message.*

WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.
ERROR: "PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'PowerShellGet'".

`Update-Module PowerShellGet`

ERROR: "Update-Module : Module 'PowerShellGet' was not installed by using Install-Module, so it cannot be updated.".

`Update-Module PowerShellGet -Force`

ERROR: "Update-Module : Module 'PowerShellGet' was not installed by using Install-Module, so it cannot be updated.".

`Find-Module dbatools`

- *NOTE: The Find-Module command pauses for many minutes before the command returns an error message.*

ERROR: "No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'dbatools'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories."

`Get-PSRepository | fl *`

Name                      : PSGallery

SourceLocation            : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2

Trusted                   : False

Registered                : True

InstallationPolicy        : Untrusted

PackageManagementProvider : NuGet

PublishLocation           : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/

ScriptSourceLocation      : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript

ScriptPublishLocation     : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/

ProviderOptions           : {}

`Get-Module PackageManagement -ListAvailable`

Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands

Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-Packa...

Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-Packa...

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable |
 Where-Object ModuleBase -like $env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\* |
 Sort-Object -Property Name, Version -Descending |
 Get-Unique -PipelineVariable Module |
 ForEach-Object {
     if (-not(Test-Path -Path "$($_.ModuleBase)\PSGetModuleInfo.xml")) {
         Find-Module -Name $_.Name -OutVariable Repo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
         Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $_ -Property Name, Version |
         Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>' |
         Select-Object -Property Name,
                                 Version,
                                 @{label='Repository';expression={$Repo.Repository}},
                                 @{label='InstalledVersion';expression={$Module.Version}}
     }

 }
```

WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.

```
$webclient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12"
Find-Module dbatools
```

WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.

PackageManagement\Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'dbatools'. Try
Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.

`Invoke-WebRequest https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2`

Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

---

**Some references I tried**

windows 10 - Powershell won't install almost any module using install-module - Stack Overflow
[Powershell won't install almost any module using install-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165095/powershell-wont-install-almost-any-module-using-install-module)

There's a script for that: Install-Module - unable to resolve package source 'https //www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/'
https://vanbrenk.blogspot.com/2017/09/install-module-unable-to-resolve.html

Update Manually Installed PowerShell Modules from the PowerShell Gallery – Mike F Robbins
https://mikefrobbins.com/2016/06/09/update-manually-installed-powershell-modules-from-the-powershell-gallery/

Update-Module : Module 'PowershellGet' was not installed by using Install-Module, so it cannot be updated. - Evotec
https://evotec.xyz/update-module-module-powershellget-was-not-installed-by-using-install-module-so-it-cannot-be-updated/

Comment: Does `Find-Module dbatools` work?

Comment: Find-Module dbatools response is `No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'dbatools'. Try
Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.` I think the repo is registered.

Comment: What's the output of `Get-PSRepository | fl *`

Comment: Get-PSRepository | fl * output is `Name                      : PSGallery
SourceLocation            : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
Trusted                   : False
Registered                : True
InstallationPolicy        : Untrusted
PackageManagementProvider : NuGet
PublishLocation           : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/
ScriptSourceLocation      : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript
ScriptPublishLocation     : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/
ProviderOptions           : {}`

Comment: If this is a home system, this would be surprising. If this is a corporate/enterprise-managed machine, then they could be blocking you. I've seen blocking this in several customer environments.

Comment: It's a corporate PC. I've been using PS for a couple years at my corporation, and I have installed other modules before. What else can I check to get this resolved?

Comment: Do you get a valid response if you just send an HTTP request to the gallery directly? ie. `Invoke-WebRequest https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Updated the posting with the results. The underlying connection was closed.

Comment: It could be a TLS issue. Try forcing TLS1.2 by running the following command first:
`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabled Group Policy to allow scripts and set execution policy to bypass. I am now able to install the module. However, I must run the install with Scope current user and am still unable to install with As Admin powershell.

Module Install

```
Install-Module DBATools -Scope CurrentUser
```

Group Policy (Fix)

```
#*****************
FIX ...
#*****************

## PS (As Admin)
gpedit.msc
# Navigate to: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows PowerShell. Change the “Turn on Script Execution”
# Turn on Script Execution > Enabled, Policy "Allow all scripts"

## PS (As Admin)
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell -Name ExecutionPolicy -Value ByPass


<# 
#*****************
REFERENCE ...
#*****************
 Windows PowerShell - the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope
 https://vladtalkstech.com/2015/03/windows-powershell-updated-execution-policy-successfully-setting-overridden-policy-defined-specific-scope.html

 Change the PowerShell MachinePolicy Execution Policy in WS 2012R2
 https://vladtalkstech.com/2014/03/change-powershell-machinepolicy-execution-policy-windows-server-2012r2.html
#>


#*****************
CAUSE ...
#*****************

Get-ExecutionPolicy –List

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope MachinePolicy Unrestricted

## However, you might have an error saying it can only be done via Group Policy.
## “Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes mustbe set through Group Policy
```

Answer (score 42):

I ran into the same error installing different module.  My fix was specifying TLS1.2 for the .net Security protocol.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: Worked great when I RDP'd in. Didn't work in PowerShell remoting (`Enter-PSSession`).

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was trying to use TLSv1.3 and was getting the "cant find package" error. Changed to using TLSv1.2 and it works. Kinda crazy to me that the newer TLS version doesn't work.

Comment: Makes no difference at all.  See aditya's correct answer below.

Answer (score 26):

Try running `Register-PSRepository -Default`

Comment: This worked for me on a Win 2016 Standard with PSVersion 5.1.14393.2969 box, but only after I issued the TLS config setting mentioned in the answer by @Stephen

Comment: `PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : Module Repository 'PSGallery' exists.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:4211 char:17
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource @PSBoundParamete .`

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to Stephen, rouxquasar it worked with below order for me Windows 2016 Datacenter, KB4598243, Execution policy was set properly so didn't have to deal with that.

1. Enable `TLS 1.2`:

   `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`
2. Register the default PS Gallery Repo (may check `Get-PSRepository | fl*` just incase)

   `Register-PSRepository -Default`
3. `Install-Module dbatools` (check `Find-Module` before to validate)

Use `-Force` switch if an older version of `dbatools` exists.

Answer (score 8):

Re-registering PS default repository as an Administrator fixed for me:

```
  [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
  Unregister-PSRepository -Name PSGallery
  Register-PSRepository -Default
  Find-Module dbatools
```

Comment: Unregistering is the only thing that would solve it for me. Don't overlook this answer if all the TLS and Register actions aren't doing anything for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried register-psrepository and it executed with out any error but after when I try get-psrepository its was still giving same error message "WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.", I tried different option below steps worked for me:

1. register ps repository with a different name and use the same psgallery api for source location.
   Register-PSRepository **PSGallery1** -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
2. set the repository
   Set-PSRepository PSGallery1
3. now when I check the repository it worked like charm
   [PSGAllery1 is the Name I have used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD2O0.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try running the `powerShell` or the `WindowsTerminal` **as administrator**, and then re-entering your command before trying any complicated solution, helps most of the time.

Comment: This should have been a comment.